# Does Bob know the state of the qubit Alice teleported after the completion of the teleportation protocol?

Tags: entanglement, teleportation, bell-basis

Notation: $|\text{Alice}_{1\,\,}\text{Alice}_{2\,\,}\text{Bob}_{1}\rangle$

Alice and Bob shared an entangled state, say a Bell state $| \Phi_{+}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg[|00\rangle + |11\rangle\bigg] $.

A source transmit a prepared state $|\psi\rangle_{A_{0}} = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$ to Alice and Alice wants for Bob to know $|\psi\rangle_{A_{0}}$. She is restricted from measuring $|\psi\rangle_{A_{0}}$ as it would collapse this state.

The protocol is as follows:

1. $|\psi\rangle_{A_{0}}| \Phi_{+}\rangle$.
2. Apply $CNOT_{\text{Alice}_1  \to \text{Alice}_2 }$.
3. Apply $H$ to $\text{Alice}_1$.

The outcome is

$$\begin{align}
&(H\otimes I \otimes I)(CNOT_{\text{Alice}_1  \to \text{Alice}_2 })(|\psi\rangle_{A_{0}}| \Phi_{+}\rangle)\\ 
&= \frac{1}{2}\bigg[|00\rangle (\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle) + |01\rangle (\beta|0\rangle + \alpha|1\rangle) + |10\rangle (\alpha|0\rangle - \beta |1\rangle) + |11\rangle (-\beta|0\rangle + \alpha|1\rangle) \bigg]
\end{align}$$

Alice's eigenstate: ${|00\rangle, |01\rangle, |10\rangle, |11\rangle}$

Bob's eigenstate: ${(\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle), (\beta|0\rangle + \alpha |1\rangle), (\alpha|0\rangle -\beta |1\rangle), (-\beta|0\rangle + \alpha|1\rangle)}$

Probability amplitude: each eigenstate of Alice's and Bob's has a probability amplitude of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

**All is good up until this point: at my point my understanding is that Bob is still unaware of the prepared state $|\psi\rangle_{A_{0}} = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$.**

Now, Alice then communicates to Bob what her eigenstates are and depending on what the eigenstate is, **Bob applies a suitable sequence of unitary gate(s) to attain $|\psi\rangle_{A_{0}} = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|0\rangle$.**

Example: **Alice communicates $|00\rangle$ to Bob. Bob applies an identity gate $\mathbb{I}$ to $(\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle)$ so that he gets the prepared state $|\psi\rangle_{A_{0}} = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|0\rangle$**. But this implies Bob knows what $|\psi\rangle_{A_{0}} = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$ is.

How does Bob knows what $|\psi\rangle_{A_{0}} = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|0\rangle$ is?

Comment: What do you mean by - "But this implies bob knows what $|\psi \rangle_{A_a}$ is." ?

Comment: @FDGod Bob applies some specific operation to go from an eigenstate of his to a desired eigenstate. How does he knows what to apply if he has no knowledge of what this desired eigenstate is? Am I missing some subtlety in the narrative/ protocol?

Comment: Bob applies that operator based on what Alice measures. Alice performs bell-basis measurement; she gets one of the four outcomes. She sends this "classical information" of her measurement outcomes, which are 00 or 01 or 10 or 11, to Bob. And depending on this, Bob applies some operations and retrieves back the $|\psi\rangle$. During the whole procedure and after, neither Alice nor Bob knows what the state is.

Comment: The qubit which Bob has now exists in the state $| \psi \rangle$. Bob doesn't know what that state $| \psi \rangle$ is.

Comment: @FDGod This is shedding some light. Can I assume that for Bob to apply operation $A$ when he receives $|00\rangle$ from Alice, it must be true that a pre - existing dictionary has been agreed upon as like in the superdense coding protocol?

Comment: Yes exactly. Alice and Bob both agree on a "dictionary" prior to starting this protocol, which says which operation Bob should perform depending on the measurement outcome Alice gets.

Comment: @FDGod Thank you. Odd that almost all resources do not state this information.

Comment: @FDGod But what dictates how the dictionary should be designed if this is the first time they have ever conducted this protocol?

Comment: Just one more comment: you mention that "dictionary exists which says Bob apply operation $A$ when he receives $|00\rangle $ from Alice. This 2-bit information "00" doesn't need to be a qubit. It can be classical information which Alice sends to Bob. Also, which resources are you using? Checkout Mark Wilde's QIT book, section 6.2.4.

Comment: @FDGod I agree "00" doesn't have to be a qubit - $|00\rangle$ is just a quantum analog of the classical bit 00

Comment: The dictionary could be arbitrary depending on the basis you are working in. Typically, When Alice sends 00, Bob does nothing, i.e. Apply identity. When Alice sends 01, Bob applies $Z$. When Alice sends 10, Bob applies $X$ and when Alice sends 11, Bob applies $XZ$ to his qubit.